# why does ionic2 storage fail to retrieve value?

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic2 storage a below:

```
//page2.ts
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class LoginPage {
   ...

  //this works fine
  onLogin(){
    this.storage.set('uid', '12345');
  }

}

//page2.ts

export class Foo {

   //no value gets retrieved here
  onSave() {
    this.storage.get('uid')
    .then(uid =>  console.log(uid));
  }
}
```

No value gets retrieved and no error is thrown, what am i missing ?

Comment: Did you check browser db If the value is there?

Comment: check your plugin folder whether you are seeing stroage folder if not install one

Comment: I faced the same problem few days ago. what happene is, you do get the value in (uid) but console.log(uid) gets executed before your storage retrieves the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NativeStorage.  It is one of native-ionic plugins and it won't be deleted unless you programmatically delete it or user deletes an app. With NativeStorage you would do.

```
NativeStorage.setItem('uid',{value: this.uid}.then(()=>{
console.log("uid is saved);
})

NativeStorage.getItem('uid').then((data)=>{
console.log("uid value is: " + data.value);
})
```